# Determine lambda from a non-constant differentiable function of one variable

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, partial-fractions

Suppose *f* is a non-constant differentiable function of one variable.
Determine, with reasons, the value of $\lambda$ for which

*F(x, y) = f($\lambda x^{3}$ + y)* 
satisfies the partial differential equation
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$+ $x^{2}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$= 0.

I tried to treat *f($\lambda x^{3} + y)$* as a normal equation as $\lambda x^{3} + y$
and do partial differentiation
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ = 3$\lambda x^{2}$
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ = 1

then I substitute these two answers back to the partial differential equation:
3$\lambda x^{2}$+$x^{2}$=0
$x^2$(3$\lambda$+1)=0

$\lambda$=$\frac{-1}{3}$

I am not sure if I am right or not, would someone help please?

Comment: We have $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 3\lambda x^2 \times f'(\lambda x^3 +y)$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = f'(\lambda x^3 +y)$ by the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

Comment: luckily, the answer is still the same, thank you~